# SQL how to Join two tables

Tags: sql

Table a is joined with another two tables using the code below.

### Code

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
 PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO,
 PY.DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN,
 COALESCE (SV.EMPLOYEE_CODE,MEM.EMPLOYEE_CODE) AS EMPLOYEE_CODE,
 SV.HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX,
 SV.PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE, 
 SV.SERVICE_CODE,
 SV.SUBJECT_TYPE
 FROM PY_DEDUCTION PY
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SERVICE SV ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = SV.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SV_GRP_MEMBER MEM ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = MEM.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)

Display Table a
SUBJECT_TYPE   PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE Employee_code DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO  SERVICE_CODE   HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX   DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN
EMP                                     001          D2001               AC01            $50                        $40
GRP                GP1005               001          D2001               AC02            $100                       $80 
GRP                GP1005               002          D2001               AC02            $70                        $20
EMP                                     003          D2233               AC05            $100                       $100
```

Now need to join with Table b. But some Deduction_Voucher_No not include in table b

```
Table b
Payslip_Voucher_NO   Deduction_Voucher_No Employee_code OutStanding_Amount
P1001                 D2001                 001          $10
P1002                 D2001                 001          $20
P1003                 D2001                 002          $50
```

I try to apply left outer join,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
 PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO,
 PY.DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN,
 COALESCE (SV.EMPLOYEE_CODE,MEM.EMPLOYEE_CODE) AS EMPLOYEE_CODE,
 SV.HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX,
 SV.PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE, 
 SV.SERVICE_CODE,
 SV.SUBJECT_TYPE,
 tbl.Payslip_Voucher_No,
 tbl.Outstanding_Amount
 FROM PY_DEDUCTION PY
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SERVICE SV ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = SV.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SV_GRP_MEMBER MEM ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = MEM.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table b tlb ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = tbl.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
```

but it show the error, display all the payslip_voucher_no which under same DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO

```
SUBJECT_TYPE   PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE Employee_code DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO  Payslip_Voucher_NO  SERVICE_CODE   HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX   DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN  OutStanding_Amount
EMP                                     001          D2001               P1001               AC01            $50                        $40               $10
EMP                                     001          D2001               P1002               AC01            $50                        $40               $20
EMP                                     001          D2001               P1003               AC01            $50                        $40               $50
```

Expected result should be

```
SUBJECT_TYPE   PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE Employee_code DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO  Payslip_Voucher_NO  SERVICE_CODE   HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX   DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN  OutStanding_Amount
EMP                                     001          D2001               P1001               AC01            $50                        $40               $10
GRP                GP1005               001          D2001               P1002               AC02            $100                       $80               $20
GRP                GP1005               002          D2001               P1003               AC02            $70                        $20               $50
EMP                                     003          D2233               empty               AC05            $100                       $100              $0
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: General advice: You should post both your current _and_ expected output in the question.

Comment: And try to reduce your example to the minimum set, to show your problem. That helps detecting the problems. Often, while reducing the problem, you will solve it yourself.

Comment: So do another outer join, something like ... LEFT OUTER JOIN Tableb ON Tableb.Deduction_Voucher_No = ...

Comment: I got try to add another outer join to it, example left outer join table a. deduction voucher no = table b.deduction voucher no. but all the payslip voucher no. also display under same deduction voucher no

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
 PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO,
 PY.DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN,
 COALESCE (SV.EMPLOYEE_CODE,MEM.EMPLOYEE_CODE) AS EMPLOYEE_CODE,
 SV.HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX,
 SV.PIECE_RATE_GROUP_CODE, 
 SV.SERVICE_CODE,
 SV.SUBJECT_TYPE,
 ISNULL(b.OutStanding_Amount, 0) AS OutStanding_Amount -- Add this line
 FROM PY_DEDUCTION PY
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SERVICE SV ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = SV.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PY_DEDUCTION_SV_GRP_MEMBER MEM ON (PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = MEM.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO)
 -- Add this line, I don't know which table contains Payslip_Voucher_NO to avoid unwanted rows
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON 
 (
     PY.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO = b.DEDUCTION_VOUCHER_NO 
     AND ??.Payslip_Voucher_NO = b.Payslip_Voucher_NO
     AND COALESCE (SV.EMPLOYEE_CODE,MEM.EMPLOYEE_CODE) = b.EMPLOYEE_CODE
 )
```

Comment: but the output become like this when add the line,  all the payslip voucher no. also display if belong the deduction voucher no.

Comment: Only table b have payslip_voucher_no

Comment: @user3559600 Then your condition cannot be achieve with table b. But do you actually just needs `SV.HOME_AMT_AFTER_TAX - PY.DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN` as OutStanding_Amount?

Comment: Actually not. only first time can use this calculation, because for the second time deduction need to use Outstanding_Amount - PY.DEDUCTION_PER_PAYRUN